# Cant get script in custom inspector if it don't inherit anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a problem, and i have no idea how to solve it. So i have a custom inspector, and i want to make on a class which has no inhert, like a custom variable. Here i will show the code and hopefully you understand

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(QuizHolder))]
public class QuizHolderInspector : Editor {
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        QuizHolder myScript = (QuizHolder)target;//This produces a squigly line, and makes the error : "Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.Object' to 'QuizHolder'"
        MakePublic("m_Script");
        MakePublic("NameOfQuizHolder");
        MakePublic("Whichquiz");
        //if (qui == QuizHolder.WhichQuiz.NumberQuiz)
        //{

        //}
    }
    void MakePublic(string smart)
    {
        var property2 = serializedObject.FindProperty(smart);
        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property2, true);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}`
```

also the quizholder code is :`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class QuizHolder {//As you see here, it doesnt inherit monodevolep, and i think that is the problem, but i don't know how to fix it since i need it to not inherit monodevolep
    public string NameOfQuizHolder;
    public enum WhichQuiz {NumberQuiz,OptionQuiz,InputFieldQuiz};
    public WhichQuiz Whichquiz;
    public NumberQuiz Numberquiz;
    public OptionQuiz Optionquiz;
    public InputFieldQuiz InputFieldquiz;
}`
```

please help me, i am a bit tired so sorry if it doesnt make sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

*At the very least* your `QuizHolder` needs to extend `Component` otherwise it cannot be attached to a GameObject.

If the problem is that it needs to be a serialized field for the Editor script, then it needs to extend `UnityEngine.Object` at a minimum (`UnityEngine.Object` is not the same as `System.Object`, which is what all classes inherit from by default).

I'm only about 80% confident that the latter case is your problem, but it's not entirely clear to me. This assumption is due to your comment `"Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.Object' to 'QuizHolder'"`

Comment: well is there any way to make custom inspector in custom values?

Comment: @Sinci1 extend `UnityEngine.Object` or a subclass thereof.

Comment: @Sinci1 `public class QuizHolder : UnityEngine.Object`

Comment: thanks for replying, but sadly that doesnt work. i will still mark your answer as checkmark,because you took the time out of your day/night to help me!